# Как перевести файл CMS на русский

Tags: php, notepad++, перевод

Как перевести много строк в файле?
Вот пример  строк :

```
"login" => "Login",
"login_here" => "Login Here",
"login_email" => "Email",
```

Нужно чтобы было:

```
"login" => "Логин",
"login_here" => "Логин продолжить",
"login_email" => "Емайл",
```

И так 1000 строк?

---

Вопрос в том как скопировать правую часть и потом вставить вместо нее уже другое

Comment: Просто возникла такая проблема.  Я только начинаю. Если кто подскажет, буду  благодарен!

Comment: Вариант 1 - ручной ввод. Вариант 2 - через переводчик

Comment: Не ясно в чем именно проблема. У вас сам переводы есть? В каком они виде?